# Surprising behavior of numpy.random.shuffle

Tags: python, numpy

while using the numpy.random.shuffle in my own function, it accidentally changed my global variable. I'm not sure if it is there some misunderstanding on its usage.

The numpy version is '1.16.4'

```py
import numpy as np
def shuffle_test(a):
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    b=a
    return b

outer_input  = np.array(range(10))
print(outer_input)

outer_output = shuffle(outer_input)
print(outer_input)
```

Here's the result
input before shuffle:

```py
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

input after shuffle:

```py
[5 4 7 1 8 2 6 0 9 3]
```

Comment: if you find something unexpected in a package as widely used as `numpy` it is nearly always a 'bug' in your *understanding* rather than in the package *implementation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not accidental; it is the described behavior of [np.random.shuffle](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html)

> Modify a sequence in-place by shuffling its contents

you could do like this:

```
import numpy as np

outer_input  = np.array(range(10))
np.random.shuffle(outer_input)
outer_input

# array([1, 9, 7, 4, 3, 6, 0, 5, 2, 8])   # for instance
```